Please help me out with this logic of integration.
Generally while integrating floor function we put the lower and the upper limits directly. But is that way correct ?
For e.g. while integrating $[x]$ , $[x^{2}]$ generally we directly put the lower and upper limits.
For example :
$$\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx$$
Now to integrate $[x]$ from $0$ to $1$, we generally write the integral in the above format.
But I think this is wrong. Let me explain why ?
We know that $[x]=0$ when $0<x<1$
Therefore according to me I think we should write the given integral in this way.
$$\lim_{(m,n)\to (0^{+},1^{-})}\int_{m}^{n}[x]dx$$
But almost in $99.7$ % books, the integral of $[x]dx$ from $0$ to $1$ is written  in the way
$$\int_{0}^{1}[x]dx$$
Please tell me who is correct ? Me or the book ?

What difference would it make? The value of the integrand at a single point doesn't affect the integral anyway.

Imagine the Riemann sum of this function: all terms are zero and only the last term may not be zero, but will simply be equal to the last subinterval in the partition of the entire interval. But the limit of this last subinterval tends to zero.

If the $0$ and $1$ are given, then why would we introduce limits for those? Do you think limits are a point of elegance?

We know that $[x]=0$ when $0\le x<1$ and $[1]=1$. Consider the function $f(x)\equiv0$. Then, $f(x)=[x]$ for all $x$ except $x=1$. The integral is unaffected by changes in the value of the function at finitely many points (or in general, any set of measure zero). Hence, it is justified to write
$$\int_0^1[x]\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^10\,\mathrm dx$$
Hope this helps. :)
